# AngularJS - unable to compare values in ngSelected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compare, comparison

I'm trying to auto-select an <option> using ngSelected inside an ngRepeat.

One option has "selected" attribute in the generated html and between <option> tags, but the <select> doesn't seem to have a selected option.

```
$scope.selected = 2;
$scope.isSelected = function(x) {
  return (x == $scope.selected);
};

$scope.myList = [{
  "id": "1", "name": "aaa"
}, {
  "id": "2", "name": "bbb"
}, {
  "id": "3", "name": "xxx"
}];
```

...

```
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option ng-repeat="item in myList" value="{{item.id}}" 
     ng-selected="isSelected(item.id)">
       {{item.name}} [selected {{item.id == selected}}]</option>
</select>
```

I've tried to parseInt values, cast them to string, eval the comparison... but it's the same: apparently, no option selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/monguz/yxsqgz5n/

What am I missing?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thanks for comments and replies.

The fiddle shows a simplified version of my real code.
I've already tried "selected" as string, but I cannot be 100% sure about its type.

Anyway, I don't understand why the code as-is doesn't show a selected option. 
According to docs, the expression is "truthy", so it should appear as selected.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: try $scope.selected = "2"

Answer (score 2):

I changed in jsfiddle for this and worked.

```
$scope.selected = '2';
```